# How to add dictionary values to an Array in VBA instead of reference

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary

I am sending data from Excel to the dashing.io dashboard via JSON. 
The data which I am sending consist of several touples of data like

```
[{"Group":"Interface","progress";"10"},{"Group":"HMI","progress";"20"}]
```

Right now I am using several dictionary objects progress1, progress2 to hold the data like:

```
DIM progress1 as new Dictionary
DIM progress2 as new Dictionary
progress1.add "Group", "Interface"
progress1.add "Progress", 10
progress2.add "Group", "HMI"
progress2.add "Progress", 20
```

And finally for creating the JSON object, the two progress dictionaries are added to one object:

```
Dim body as new Dictionary
body.add Array(progress1, progress2)
```

As there are more than just two progress items, I wanted to create a for-loop to add data to a dictionary and then add that dictionary item to an array like

```
for i=1 to 10
  progress.add "Group", Range(i,1)
  progress.add "progress", Range (i,2)
next i
overall_progress.add (progress)
```

It seems that I am adding the object as reference, instead of the values of the object. If the loop runs 10 times, I end up having ten times the same entry.

Any idea how to add the values of a dictionary to an array, instead of the reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating objects in a loop is easier to manage if you use a "factory" function.

E.g:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim body As New Collection, i As Long

    For i = 1 To 10
        body.Add Progress(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 2))
    Next i

End Sub

Function Progress(grp, prog) As Object
    Dim rv As New scripting.dictionary
    rv.Add "Group", grp
    rv.Add "Progress", prog
    Set Progress = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Wow, great! I had to use
"Dim rv as New Dictionary"
but apart from that, it now works great. Thanks a lot!